# Android App Update programmatically shows open button instead update button

Tags: android, google-play, apk

In my project using the the code `curr_appversion = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME, 0).version Name;` to get the current version code of the app and we already having web service which provide the play store version (Actually we update the data after app publish in the play store).Comparing both of the version value show the dialog to update the app.`if(Double.parseDouble(curr_appversion)<Double.parseDouble(playstore_appversion))`

Before some update the above mention scenario is working perfectly and able to update the app (showing dialog for new app update available) programmatically.
Now after last time after publishing the apk to play store and also my device upgrade to android 6.0.

Now if we try the above mention concept to update the app programmatically its redirect to the play store perfectly 
Code used to redirect from to the google play store
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName+"&hl=en")));
But instead of showing the update button it shows open button ,due to this user move to the app instead of updating it.

Some of the stackoverflow link mentioned that you should use apk which is generate with release key certficate.
For this already checked using the keytool command for live apk (apk now in play store ) and the update apk

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile original.apk
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile update.apk
```

The both certificate shows identical.

So can anyone please why this scenario is appearing while following the above concept to update the app programmatically. Need to make change in my code.

Comment: Update button comes if google play has an application with some update and version change. In your case it sems you forgot to update version for updated apk

Comment: If that scenario happen with me forgot to update the version code and version name in build.gradle than play store gives error that u cannot update with the same version.because perviously i had version as 10 and now its update to 11.Anyway thanks for the reply

Comment: any possibility that logged in user ID in Play store currently and user ID used to installed app are different? if you have mulitple user's in play store. try changing them?

Comment: Also when was the app updated to play store? If it's day or two. Please note it takes time to roll out to all users, as it's staged roll out. Try clearing out cache of your play store & reboot to see if that gives you a update option. There is nothing wrong in your code